# Displaying node translations

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have enabled several languages on my site and the following modules has been installed: Locale & Content translation.
I have created a simple page in English and have added several translations for this node.
Now when I view node on separate page it's displaying in language which is selected in language switcher block.
But if I view node on front-page (/node) or on taxonomy page (taxonomy/term/%) all translations of this node has been shown.
Is it possible to disable displaying other translations for all pages?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views), which comes with a front page view you can modify to make it show only nodes for a specific language, and a view for taxonomy/term/%. For taxonomy terms, it is not so straight, as Drupal associates a language to nodes, but not taxonomy terms; it still is possible to show only the nodes associated with the selected taxonomy term, and which are written in a specific language.

If you install the development snapshot of Views (7.x-3.x-dev), some settings have been renamed; the one that you should change is "filter criteria."

[image: Views screenshot]